# Javascript square function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to write a function that checks if the given number has a certain order.

The second number has to be the square of the previous number.
The first number can only be 0 - 9.

So for example 2439 would return 'true' because 4 is the square of 2 and 9 is the square of 3.

39416 would also give 'true', and for example 1624 would return 'false'.

I don't really have an idea how to do this. It should be a recursive function but an example of how to do it without recursion would be helpfull too.

Comment: The 'firsts' numbers will be limited to the space of 0 to 9? That is, the squared numbers can be higher than 10, but the numbers to be squared will always be less than 10?

Comment: Good exercise, ticky if the 'firsts' aren't limited to `0..9` as Marco asked. I loved those homeworks.

Comment: Could you explain how 39416 would give true?

Comment: 3 is the square root of 9. 4 is the square root of 16.

Comment: The first numbers would indeed be limited to 9.

Comment: I see, then it is not just the previous digit as I was assuming, but it could be 1+ digits number.

Comment: Does it also need to return true for 4 16 25 625 256 65536 ?

Comment: @XGreen No, as OP mentioned, the numbers that will be powered (the 'firsts') are limited to 0..9

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
function isOrdered(input){ 

    var position = 0;

    while(position<input.length-2)
    {

        var currentFirstNumber = parseInt(input[position]);

        if(currentFirstNumber<=2) {
            if (Math.sqrt(parseInt(input[position + 1])) !== currentFirstNumber)
                return false;
            else
                position+=2;
        }

       if(currentFirstNumber>=4 && currentFirstNumber<=9)
       {
           var squared = input.substring(position+1,position+3);

           if(Math.sqrt(parseInt(squared))!==currentFirstNumber)
               return false;
           else
               position=position+3;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(isOrdered("2439"));    // outputs true
console.log(isOrdered("39416"));   // outputs true
console.log(isOrdered("1624"));    // outputs false
```

I pass the number to the function as a string.

Comment: This wouldn't work for the `39416` example provided by the OP.

Comment: this one gives isOrdered("39982") as true

Comment: @XGreen thanks for your comment. I will try to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @XGreen thank you once more for your note. I have made two stupid errors. One in the if conditions and one misuse of string.substring :(.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the comment section, OP said that the 'firsts' are limited to 0..9. So the easiest way to accomplish this is by going through the `power` function instead of the `square root` function.

---

UPDATE: Sorry, you asked for JavaScript code. Be careful with the `FIRST CALL`. if you manually pass to the function the last position, it will return true.

```
function verification(number, position){        
    var str = String(number);                        // Cast number to String
    if(str.length > position){                       // Verify valid position
        var value = str.substr(position, 1);         // take the 'first' value
        var pow = Math.pow(value, 2);                // Calculate the power
        // Verify if the next value is equivalent to the power
        if(str.indexOf(pow, position) == position + 1){   
            // Recursive call to verify the next position
            return verification(number, position + String(pow).length + 1);
        } else {
            // If not equivalent, you found an inconsistency. 
            return false;
        }
    // If you ran it until you reached the last position, you're good to go.
    }else if(str.length == position){
        return true;
    }
}

console.log(verification(39416, 0)); // True
console.log(verification(39415, 0)); // True
console.log(verification(981524, 0)); // false
console.log(verification(981525, 0)); // true
console.log(verification(98525, 0)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this recursive function

```
function detectOrder(input)
{
    var input = input.toString()
    var first = input.substr(0,1);
    var power = Math.pow(parseInt(first), 2);
    var powerLength = power.toString().length;
    if ( parseInt(input.substr(1, powerLength)) == power )
    {
        if (input.length <= 1+powerLength)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return detectOrder(input.substr(1+powerLength));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```